# URL to authenticated page doesn't work when user needs to login

Tags: community

I have a website URL https://niimbl.force.com/s/2020-niimbl-symposium that is accessible when a user is logged into our Community.

However, if a guest user goes to the URL, he is prompted to login.  After successfully logging in, he receives an error that the page doesn't exist because it is taking him to https://niimbl.force.com/2020-niimbl-symposium  The needed /s is getting stripped out of the URL.

Comment: I am interested in others suggestions, but I put a workaround in place by creating two redirects to accomplish what I wanted.  The key to making the login go to the correct page was to point it to a record id & then redirect to the custom community page.  I couldn't get the startURL to work with a custom page.  Here is what I used...
https://niimbl.force.com/s/login/?startURL=%2Fa0M3u0000092b7SEAQ

Comment: Can you just double confirm whether the community was active and you published your changes, you will see /s after you published only

Comment: Yes, the community has been published for several years.  The /s is always there.  I got this to work by using the startURL parameter in the URL.  When I didn't use that, Salesforce was stripping away the /s that is needed to go to the correct page.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to see if you have the same problem.  If you have a URL for an authenticated only page, try accessing it as a guest user.  You will be prompted to login.  At that point, I would be interested in knowing if it takes you to the correct page or if you receive an error like I did.

Comment: The start URL is correct so the redirect should happen properly. Do you have standard authentication or have you built a custom one?

Comment: I am doing more troubleshooting & have found that when I login to the portal with my system administrator account, the URL works correctly after login.  However, when I login with a standard customer community account, the URL doesn't work after the user logs in.  It is as if two different login pages are being used.  I see a visual difference between the screens which further indicates that two different login pages are being used.

Comment: I have determined that the problem occurs when a portal user has two-factor authentication enabled.  This doesn’t seem to be a problem with users who don’t have 2FA.  Thoughts on what I need to change to make this work correctly?  Things work correctly when I include the startURL extension to a URL.  I don't feel like I should need to do this.  I don't need to for non-2FA users.

Comment: How do I set the startURL when I want it to go to a Community Page that is not associated with a record?